# NodeJS: shorter way to create a conditional property in an object than self-invoked function? (either ES5 or ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, self-invoking-function

Is there a shorter way to express the following? (either ES5 or ES6)

```
res.cookie('abc', 'xyz', (function(){
            var obj = {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true };
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV==="production"){
                obj.secure = true;
            }
            return obj;
        })());
```

Comment: **Primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  So, this one should be close!

Comment: i mean... "shorter" isn't an opinion generating request. it just isn't a metric that should be used to define good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 offers the `Object.assign` method, which you might be able to use like so:

```
var obj = Object.assign(
  {
    maxAge: 900000,
    httpOnly: true,
  },
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? { secure: true }
    : {}
)
```

That will ensure that the key `secure` is not even present in the final object if the environment isn't production. If you're okay with the key being there, but with a value of `false`, then:

```
var obj = {
  maxAge: 900000,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
}
```

will suffice.

---

In even newer versions of ECMAScript, you have access to object destructuring using the `...` operator. So you could turn the first snippet into a more concise version:

```
var obj = {
  maxAge: 900000,
  httpOnly: true,
  ...process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? { secure: true }
    : {},
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
res.cookie('abc', 'xyz', {
  maxAge: 900000,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
});
```

Comment: This is not the same. Secure will be false where in the original code was not present.

Comment: @lilezek You are right but I think `secure: false` will work.

Comment: @Emilio can tell

Comment: Yes, at first I wrote my question like @lilezek read it. By using a self-invoked function, I was trying not to use "secure" property in the object.  But I was over-thinking, because the "secure" property is by default false, so Zohaib Ijaz is right with his answer.  Thanks all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator since ternaries are expressions.

```
   res.cookie('abc', 'xyz', {
      maxAge: 9 * 100 * 1000,
      httpOnly:true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV==="production" ? true : undefined
    });
```